# Derivation Gauss's law for material mediums in the differential form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauss-law, dielectric

Given Gauss's law for the vacuum in the differential form, 
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = \frac {\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$$
How can it be used to derive its version for material mediums, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{D} = \rho$?

Comment: This is a classical topic in electrodynamics. I would recommend, for example, consulting `Chapter 4. Electric Fields in Matter` of `Introduction to Electrodynamics` by Griffiths. I was able to find the pdf of the book easily by googling.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\mathbf D= \varepsilon_0 \mathbf E + \mathbf P$, so

\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf D &= \nabla \cdot (\varepsilon_0 \mathbf E + \mathbf P)\\
&= \varepsilon_0 (\nabla \cdot \mathbf E) + \nabla \cdot \mathbf P
\end{align}

Now we can use Gauss' Law and the fact that $-\nabla \cdot \mathbf P$ is equal to the total bound charge density, $\rho _{\text{bound}}$. Therefore,

\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf D &= \varepsilon _0 \left(\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon _0}\right) - \rho _{\text{bound}}\\
&=\rho - \rho _{\text{bound}}
\end{align}

But $\rho = \rho _{\text{free}} + \rho _{\text{bound}}$, thus

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf D = \rho_{\text{free}}$$